# How do I debug this Memory Error in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I'm at the tail-end of my code, I get this error "Memory Error". However, I ran psutil.virtual_memory() to check on my memory and it seems just fine. Please let me know if anyone is familiar with what this may be about.

> `import psutil; print(psutil.virtual_memory())`

OUT:`svmem(total=17065791488, available=12255887360, percent=28.2, used=4809904128, free=12255887360`)

```
A = pd.merge(df_1[['id','a_id','app','del','count','date1','date2','date3']],
                          df_2,how='left',on='id')

A = pd.merge(A,df_3[['ID','T']],how='left',left_on='id',right_on='ID').drop_duplicates()
```

**ERROR**

---

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-344-16cb980bccfa> in <module>
----> 1 A = pd.merge(A,df_3[['ID','T']],how='left',left_on='id',right_on='ID').drop_duplicates()
      2 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     81         validate=validate,
     82     )
---> 83     return op.get_result()
     84 
     85 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in get_result(self)
    640             self.left, self.right = self._indicator_pre_merge(self.left, self.right)
    641 
--> 642         join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
    643 
    644         ldata, rdata = self.left._data, self.right._data

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_info(self)
    857             )
    858         else:
--> 859             (left_indexer, right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
    860 
    861             if self.right_index:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_indexers(self)
    836         """ return the join indexers """
    837         return _get_join_indexers(
--> 838             self.left_join_keys, self.right_join_keys, sort=self.sort, how=self.how
    839         )
    840 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how, **kwargs)
   1318     join_func = _join_functions[how]
   1319 
-> 1320     return join_func(lkey, rkey, count, **kwargs)
   1321 
   1322 

pandas\_libs\join.pyx in pandas._libs.join.left_outer_join()

MemoryError:
```

Comment: We need more context for this, at least some information on the program.

Comment: I'm reading tables from a data lake, manipulating the tables and columns with conditions, and then writing the tables to an excel spreadsheet. It's just odd that I'm getting this vague memory error when I have enough memory. I've never seen this before.

Comment: Is anyone familiar with this error?    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in take_nd(arr, indexer, axis, out, fill_value, mask_info, allow_fill)
   1712             # (s.t. df.values is c-contiguous and df._data.blocks[0] is its
   1713             # f-contiguous transpose)
-> 1714             out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype, order="F")
   1715         else:
   1716             out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)

MemoryError:

Comment: Are you sure you have enough memory? How did you calculate/estimate it?